# How can I match only round bracket by excluding the content within the same using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have String lower(Type) or LOWER(Type)

I have to replace the word lower() or LOWER() so that output should be

Type

To fix this issue I will need a regular expression which matches only lower() or LOWER() word and exclude any content present within Lower() or LOWER()

I have tried below regular expression -

```
lower\(.*\)
```

but it matches complete word including content within round bracket

Comment: What about escaping the brackets with backslashes?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am trying to do it in Java

Comment: Lets say String is "ORDER BY LOWER(TYPE)" then output should be "ORDER BY TYPE" But I will need some regx to match  LOWER() only so that I can use String.replace("regx"," "ORDER BY LOWER(TYPE)")==>"ORDER BY TYPE"

Comment: Please provide more context on how you use the regex. I think what you will need to  do is to keep what is inside (by matching it). Have you heard of "lookaround"s?

Comment: Ah yes, that is it. Please [edit] that into the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking about how to only *match* the strings you want using `Matcher.matches` or `Matcher.find`, you can use `String.replaceAll` to replace the string that matches a pattern with another string.

You can use this regex:

```
(?i)lower\(([^)]*)\)
```

with the replacement `$1` to do this:

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("(?i)lower\\(([^)]*)\\)", "$1");
```

The regex basically matches a `lower(` case insensitively (`(?i)`) and then puts everything in the brackets into group 1 (`([^)]*)`), then it matches a closing bracket. The replacement `$1` means to replace with whatever is in group 1. This means that `lower(Type)` will be replaced by `Type`.

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/scc1vM/1)

Comment: Works Like Charm,Thanks buddy

Comment: One more thing I am able to use this regex in java and it works perfectly but it is not working when I trying to use "find and replace" using regular expression in notepad++

Comment: `$1` might be `\1` in notepad++. Try `\1`.